# Using linq to query SQL Server is causing 100s of small queries

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

LINQ does drive me nuts!  I've being using it for a number of years but still find that putting a SQL Server query together using joins takes 5 minutes compared to half a day doing the same thing in LINQ.

The following query is supposed to take a `productVersion` and retrieve the downstream `productTOC` fields and then combine them with a separate set of results from a userProduct table that shows the user's status for each `productTOC`.  There is no direct link between `userProduct` and `productTOC` as there is a versioning layer in between but I've managed to get them to connect by navigating from `productTOC` *up* to the `product` then from there down into `userProducts` and if a record exists, retrieve that.  However when I run the query I get multiple SQL queries per `productTOC`

```
    private static IEnumerable<CompositeTocDataItem> GetCompositeTocData(P42Entities ctx, int userID, RSPlatform.Data.Core.ProductVersion productVersion)
    {
        return from toc in productVersion.ProductTOCs
               orderby toc.Position
               let up = toc.ReferenceProduct?.UserProducts.Where(UP=>UP.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault()
               select new CompositeTocDataItem()
               {
                   Position = toc.Position,
                   Level = toc.Level,
                   Name = toc.Name,

                   ReferenceProductID = toc.ReferenceProductID,
                   RefCode = toc.RefCode,
                   ConditionInfo = toc.ConditionInfo,
                   LastCompletedDate = up?.LastCompletedDate,
                   Score = up?.Score,
                   ScoreStatus = up?.ScoreStatus ?? "N",
               };
    }
```

For example:

The first query that occurs is kind of what I expect:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductVersionID] AS [ProductVersionID], 
    [Extent1].[Position] AS [Position], 
    [Extent1].[Level] AS [Level], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[RefCode] AS [RefCode], 
    [Extent1].[ReferenceProductID] AS [ReferenceProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ConditionInfo] AS [ConditionInfo]
    FROM [dbo].[ProductTOC] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ProductVersionID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=177
```

but then there are two separate queries for *each and every* `productTOC` like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    ...
    [Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode]
    FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=79
```

and

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[OrganisationID] AS [OrganisationID], 
    ....
    [Extent1].[LastAccessedDate] AS [LastAccessedDate]
FROM [dbo].[UserProduct] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ProductID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=79
```

If I was doing this in SQL I would simply join the tables and retrieve what I need in a single query.  Can anyone advise why I am getting lots of little lookups?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're finding that SQL is easier to write, why not just *write SQL*? Micro ORM's like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) make that easy.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Dappy @mason.  I feel like everyone in the developer community says "use linq" but I only ever find it useful in the most simple of cases.

Comment: There is a let in your query that is called for every match. If you can do this in SQL with joins then likely there is a way to rewrite your LINQ query in an optimized way. If not, you might do it by getting the two data sets to local first (then there wouldn't be any more SQL calls).

Comment: Would highly recommend Dapper.

Comment: Is this Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft EntityFramework (as per tag).

Comment: You need to write SQL by your self for efficient SQL queries.

Comment: OK, just checking. The title says "Linq to SQL", which is older, and used different strategies for query generation.

Comment: Sorry @DavidBrowne-Microsoft my title wasn't intended to suggest "Linq to SQL" technology.  I'll change.

Comment: Thanks @CetinBasoz for your suggestion.  General opinion is that I should partially or completely use traditional SQL.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "general opinion". Where is that "general opinion" referenced? Proper LINQ would work just fine.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

What if you just try to put your query outside of the other? like

```
private static IEnumerable<CompositeTocDataItem> GetCompositeTocData(P42Entities ctx, int userID, RSPlatform.Data.Core.ProductVersion productVersion)
    {
 var up = productVersion.ProductTOCs.ReferenceProduct?.UserProducts.Where(UP=>UP.UserID == userID).FirstOrDefault(); //do it HERE ..so it hit the DB only once..and then you work in memory

        return from toc in productVersion.ProductTOCs
               orderby toc.Position

               select new CompositeTocDataItem()
               {
                   Position = toc.Position,
                   Level = toc.Level,
                   Name = toc.Name,

                   ReferenceProductID = toc.ReferenceProductID,
                   RefCode = toc.RefCode,
                   ConditionInfo = toc.ConditionInfo,
                   LastCompletedDate = up?.LastCompletedDate,
                   Score = up?.Score,
                   ScoreStatus = up?.ScoreStatus ?? "N",
               };
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: It may or may not work. We don't know the actual model and interestingly OP says there is no link between userProduct and productTOC (though code says otherwise).

Comment: I will try this tomorrow.  `up` should give me the right set of `UserProduct` but `FirstOrDefault()` will need to be removed as there will be lots of rows - up to 1 per `ProductTOC`, I will then need to match up each up with each row in the results where I can - I think I'm going to have to do this in the application.

Comment: Also,@CetinBasoz is right in that I've not described by model enough, Also, yes, there is a navigable link between `userProduct` and `ProductTOC` but no direct relationship - it's a case of "up then down" with "left joins" along the way in both directions!